# what does (0..1---*) mean in a Entity-Relationship Diagram/Entity Data Model(.edmx)

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

One to many relationship is denoted by `1---*`, but I can't figure out `0..1---*`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None or One.

Basically when you have have a foreign key column that can be null.